# Reading web.config with WebConfigurationManager that contains custom sections, can't load

Tags: c#

I'm trying to put together a small helper tool to encrypt web.config files.

Linqpad example:

```
var path = @"F:\project\";

var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/",new VirtualDirectoryMapping(path,true));

var config = Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm,"/");

var c = config.Sections["customGroup"];

c.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(null);
config.Save();
```

This throws the exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'customGroupAssembly' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Adding the assembly to LinqPad fixes the errpr. I would assume this is because it's now a compile time reference.

Moving the code to a winforms application, reintroduces the issue.

I'm trying to load the needed assembly at runtime with this:

```
if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    byte[] assemblyBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(this.openFileDialog1.FileName);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyBuffer);
    MessageBox.Show("Assembly loaded!");
}
```

However it still doesn't seem to find the file.

Is there a way to load the custom assembly into the runtime app domain so that the web config can be loaded properly?

Comment: try attaching assembly resolve listener, I've had such a problem where runtime-loaded assembly was not resolved properly and needed to be manually resolved

Comment: @StenPetrov How does one go about trying that?

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s,arg)=>{ ... }` with your code at the (...)

Comment: @StenPetrov I won't pretend I understand why, but if I push the loaded assemblies into a field, then `assembly.GetName().Name == args.Name` to find the right one and return it from the `AssemblyResolve` it loads perfectly. Can you move your comment to an answer so I can give you the bounty points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching assembly resolve listener, I've had such a problem where runtime-loaded assembly was not resolved properly and needed to be manually resolved:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s,arg)=>{ ... }`

with your code at the (...) returning the assembly you want resolved based the name you got in `arg`